# Can I create equivalent of C# attribute or metadata for WPF child controls in XAML code?

Tags: wpf

Can I add some kind of custom attributes in XAML ?

Comment: I think what he means are [these kinds of Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx)

Comment: What I need is to loop through controls of a UserControl and retrieve a string attribute for each child control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean [Attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) (scroll down for info on how to create a custom one)? For examle "DockPanel.Dock" is an Attached property.

Or maybe [Markup extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx)? (though that is something a little bit different)

You can also place Attributes on custom controls and read them in code behind - just like any other .NET class, but that is not possible to do from XAML (since those are set per-type/method/..., not per-instance).

Comment: You can also place Attributes on custom controls and read them in code behind: I think that's what I want can you detail a bit more ? What I need is to loop through controls of a UserControl and retrieve a string attribute for each child control.

Comment: @user310291 What is the problem? Just loop over the children (you got answers in your other question) and read the attribute value. But as I said: Attribute values are the same for all instances of one type.

Comment: ok I didn't read this completely: I need a solution in XAML also.

Answer (score 1):

You can, using [Attatched Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).  This lets you add your own and data to the xaml on any control you choose.